# Generating very large area gamma rays by other ways other than large accelerators

Tags: radiation, laser, electrical-engineering, gamma-rays, accelerator-physics

According to this link https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a351472.pdf, HERMES III at Sandia National Labs can generate very large area gamma rays by converting the electron beam into bremsstrahlung radiations after hitting the tantalum target. As we can see in the isodose contours in the linked article especially at page 40, the gamma ray field is indeed huge. It makes sense since the target size ranges from the size of transistors to the size of military tanks.

Here, in this link https://spie.org/news/3737-gamma-ray-generation-using-a-laser-accelerated-electron-beam?SSO=1 it was said that Ti Sapphire laser systems have very high power which is at Terawatt and Petawatt level. Ti Sapphire laser systems can be used to generate gamma rays too of course with the aids of some other components, but I'm not sure if the gamma rays generated are the same size as the gamma rays produced by HERMES III.

So, my question is can we generate very large area gamma rays with Ti Sapphire laser systems? Maybe by increase the size?

Comment: Well, you know how much current at what energy you need to mimic Hermes. So, how does the laser compare and how much do you need to scale it up? Can you get an electron source large enough? Can you contain a freely propagating beam that intense easily?

Comment: @JonCuster HERMES III is 16 terawatt while the Ti Sapphire laser system is 30 terawatt, so I thought gamma rays of 30 or more MeV can be generated through it although I'm not sure if it can generate huge gamma ray fields over very large areas like the HERMES III. HERMES III generated 22MeV bremsstrahlung gamma rays while the laser system according to the second link generated >9MeV with the peak energy at 30MeV photons. So in order to generate very large gamma ray fields over huge areas, the size of the laser system must be increased?

Comment: @JonCuster thoughts?

Comment: The specs for Hermes III are the actual currents and voltages on the diode where all those gamma rays get generated. So, how big of a laser does it take to replicate those parameters? If the conversion from laser energy to electron energy and current is inefficient, then you need a really big laser (or lasers).

Comment: @JonCuster sorry I have to tell you this first, English isn't my first language. So, in conclusion, we can make big intense gamma ray fields over very large areas with titanium sapphire laser systems but the laser systems must be big. So size of the source matters. Correct?

Comment: @JonCuster sorry, thoughts?

Comment: My thought is that you have not addressed any of the points in my comments.

Comment: @JonCuster so that means we can generate huge gamma ray fields over very large areas using lasers, some other ways, etc. instead of typical big pulsed power linear accelerators, with appropriate size requirements. Thank you. Do you think a stronger fission bomb for example 10 megaton fission bomb can generate hundreds of MeV gamma rays?

Comment: You have not addressed the efficiency of converting your laser power to electron beam voltage and current. If only 10% (wildly optimistic) you will need 160TW of appropriate laser power. As for your question there, where do gamma rays come from in nuclear explosions?

Comment: @JonCuster so you're saying at least hundreds of terawatts are needed for a laser to generate voltage and current as high as HERMES III to generate similar power gamma rays, isn't it? If I remember correctly nuclear explosions produced gamma rays through Compton scattering and usually fission bombs only generated around 10 MeV or maybe a little bit higher gamma rays which is less than the HERMES III. Are there any other artificial ways to generate hundreds of MeV gamma rays over very large areas without using pulsed power linear accelerators or vacuum diodes like HERMES III?

Comment: @JonCuster sorry one more question, I forget to ask you about what determined the size of the gamma ray fields as you previously only talked about "The specs for Hermes III are the actual currents and voltages on the diode where all those gamma rays get generated". The size of the gamma ray fields depend on the size of the source too, as a smaller accelerator will only generate small gamma ray fields compared to the larger one such as HERMES III. Yes?

Comment: The report you reference has relevant info, particularly page 11 and figure 8.

Comment: @JonCuster interesting, because according to figure 8 the average photon (so, gamma ray fields) energy is much lower which is just 1.9 MeV than the average electron energy which is at 16 MeV. Shouldn't the gamma ray fields energy be actually much higher like around 20-22 MeV?

Comment: You need to review the output of Bremsstrahlung...

Comment: @JonCuster Have you seen figure 6d? According to page 11, it said the radiation volume is just 500 cm^2 but in figure 6d the radiation field is actually very large. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JonCuster "You need to review the output of Bremsstrahlung..." I just found the peak diode voltage and current, it is at page 10 but no Bremsstrahlung output. There are still some things I don't understand.

Comment: You don’t place the test object right next to the converter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115189/discussion-between-mohamed-obeidallah-and-jon-custer).