# Which one is more efficient in producing high energy gamma rays?

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, accelerator-physics

According to https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a351472.pdf the big pulsed power accelerator, HERMES III, generate electron beam with peak energy at 22 MeV and average electron energy at 16 MeV and the resulting photon energy which is bremsstrahlung radiation is approximately 2 MeV (actually 1.9 MeV) while in this link http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/80139/ this ultra compact  laser driven plasma wakefield accelerator can produce more than 109 photons per pulse with a mean energy of 10 MeV. Another link https://www.nature.com/articles/s42005-018-0095-3 said laser-solid interaction generate γ-ray that reaches 0.74 PW with the brilliance of 2 × 1024 s−1 mm−2 mrad−2 (0.1%BW)−1 at 58 MeV. So, generating gamma rays using lasers is more efficient?

Comment: To compare efficiencies  one has to compare in the same units. efficiency in what? number of photons? energy of beam?

Comment: @annav let's start with energy of resulting radiation first. In the first link, the average electron energy from the diode is 16 MeV which you can see in pg 10 while the resulting average photon energy (which is the bremsstrahlung radiation) is 1.9 MeV which you can see in pg 43 at figure 8. In the second link, the average photon energy is much higher which is at 10 MeV and it is by laser driven plasma wakefield acceleration.

Comment: It is not a value that can be quantified into an efficiency. If you want high energy photons for your experiment you choose the method that gives high energy photons, I am trying to say that efficiency is not a useful concept in this case. One cannot tell from these publications which is better. See https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/beamline/26/1/26-1-kim.pdf

Comment: see here for the use of he word in physics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency#In_physics

Comment: @annav here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/583525/generating-very-large-area-gamma-rays-by-other-ways-other-than-large-accelerator?noredirect=1#comment1323027_583525 Jon Custer said "You have not addressed the efficiency of converting your laser power to electron beam voltage and current. If only 10% (wildly optimistic) you will need 160TW of appropriate laser power." But I thought the laser system is more than efficient in generating higher energy gamma ray fields although the size of the radiation fields are not as large as the one generated by HERMES III. Any thoughts?

Comment: He is talking about a different thing, One would have to compare a synchrotron source of the same energy gammas  to the laser source. Then if there are more gammas attained with the laser source one could say that the laser source is more efiicient. Random sources cannot be compared using the word "efficient".

Comment: Take this example: it is more efficient in" time" to go by car than the bus to  the next city. It is not efficient in money spent , as the gas costs more than the bus ticket. You have to define your variable. That a particular laser source reaches an energy of 105 mev cannot be compared with a source that gives 1 MeV.

Comment: @annav thanks for the responses, Anna. In the first link in my main question, in pg 40 especially figure 6d, HERMES III gamma ray field in the outdoor mode is 8 meter wide and 20.5 meter long. That's a huge gamma ray field, considering one of the function of HERMES III is to irradiating very large test objects such as military tanks. What determined the size of gamma ray fields? Is it the size of the accelerator machine or simply the voltage and current regardless of the size of the accelerator? Can a compact laser system generated such large gamma ray fields?

Comment: It is all engineering, so I am not able to answer whether a conventional source would be better than a laser one. For the same energy gammas, a conventiinal source would be more efficient for large areas, as lasers are good at directional problems., but this is  in my opinion, it is not my field.